# Class Module vs Module in VBA

Tags: vba, class, module

I am new and trying to understand VBA.

What is the different between modules and class modules? How come I can only have Macros inside Modules. (I think I am wrong here, but I don't know how to add a macro from Class modules)

In the end I'm having to add all my event handlers inside class modules and have all my macro code inside modules.

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/

Answer (score 1):

**Modules** are global through out the code. By default recorded Macros are saved in Modules, though you can cut the code and paste the Sub/Function into a class.

`Mod1.DoSomething()`   ' Mod1 doesn't need to be instantiated, its global through the app, there is only one instane of it and that's called a Singleton pattern.

**Classes** are a concept where you need to instantiate them and their scope is limited.

`Public globalScope as New Class0`  ' <-- class0's methods are available in and outside a Module or Class.

`Private memberScope as New Class1`  ' <-- class1's methods are available inside the whole Module or Class.

`Dim localScope as New Class2`  ' <-- class2's methods are only available inside a Sub/Function.

You'll probably want to keep your event handlers in a Module as that's global. If you dispose a class with Events those events won't be available.

<sub>ps in .Net coding "Modules" are called `Static Classes`</sub>

<sub>Ps2 an fyi the difference between a Subroutine and a Function is; a Function returns a value where as a Subroutine just does something.</sub>

Comment: Also note Forms are also a class module (with some form specific stuff) and work the same way. It is also an example of what to do with a class module.

Comment: Recorded "Macros" are never Functions. They are always Subs.

Comment: Typo: `instane`

Comment: Ps2: Generally correct. However a Function can be called as you would call a Sub. And Sub ByRef parameters are mutable and are all "returned".